# Coefficient of the exceptional divisor in pullbacks of divisors along a blowing-up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$; $X$ a smooth projective variety over $k$; $Z \subseteq X$ a smooth closed sub-variety; $\mu: \widetilde X \to X$ the blowing-up of $X$ along $Z$; $E \subseteq X$ the exceptional divisor of $\mu$; $D$ a prime divisor on $X$. I want to compute the coefficient of $E$ in $\mu^\ast(D)$. It is well-known that if $Z = P$ is a closed point, then the coefficient is equal to $\mathop{\mathrm{mult}}_P(D)$. Is there similar formula for higher-dimensional $Z$? In particular, is it true that if $D \cap Z \not= \emptyset$, then $E$ has positive coefficient in $\mu^\ast(D)$?

Comment: The coefficient is the multiplicity of $D$ at a general point of $Z$. No, meeting $Z$ is not sufficient for this to be strictly positive.

Comment: @Zach Teitler, you mean the multiplicity of the local ring $\mathcal O_{Z, D}$? So the coefficient is zero unless $Z$ is contained in $D$?

Comment: Certainly, because if $Z$ is not contained in $D$ then $E$ is not contained in $\mu^{-1}(D)$ set-theoretically, thus can't be a component of the inverse image divisor.

Comment: @Will Sawin, I understand, thanks very much.